# Три массива в виде двусвязных списков?

Tags: массивы, структуры-данных, указатели, php

Ребят, подскажите мне дураку, как это можно реализовать. Предупреждаю сразу, ни математику, ни комбинаторную математику я не знаю (иначе бы я такое не спрашивал, хотя я уверен, что возможно найти решение и без этих знаний, и это тема для холивара.
Вопрос - есть три списка(массива, кортежа, пофигу). В первом из них сущности завязаны с сущностями из второго и третьего списка (т.е., у сущности A в списке 1 есть две ссылки/указателя, первый - на сущность из списка B, второй на сущность из списка C). Аналогично, сущности из списка B имеют ссылки/указатели на сущности из списков A и B, и также с списком C. Как это реализовать в языке программирования? Язык скорее всего PHP, но я готов увидеть альтернативы на чем угодно, по аналогии попытаюсь реализовать.
P.S.: - если нужно переформулировать вопрос, скажите, я попытаюсь.

Comment: Как-то не совсем понятно, причём тут комбинаторика. Можете рассказать, для какой задачи вам нужна такая структура данных?

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Заведите соответствующие структуры данных, у которых есть по два поля/свойства, ссылающиеся на экземпляры двух других типов. Затем создайте по массиву каждого типа

Comment: да, ваш ответ как раз то что напрашивалось) я просто думал что это как-то еще делается...ну вдруг) Единственный вопрос - если все три массива большие - примерно в 200 и более ключей каждый(плюс возможно один из них будет довольно многомерным), такой вариант прокатит? особенно если учесть что это на PHP а не на сях?)))

Comment: @uakob вы сейчас пытаетесь рассказать о некой сферической задаче в вакууме. Сложно, сказать, насколько оправдано такое решение с этими вашими многомерными массивами и ссылками друг на друга, не зная того, к чему всё это великолепие применяется. 

Кроме того, что значит "прокатит"? Вы о расходе памяти волнуетесь? Тогда без понятия, поскольку неизвестно, насколько велики эти ваши классы. Однако три массива по 200 (300, 500) элементов вряд ли можно назвать серьезной проблемой. Думаю, у вашего сервера есть мегабайт-другой памяти чтобы это разместить

Comment: "Однако три массива по 200 (300, 500) элементов вряд ли можно назвать серьезной проблемой" - Вы уже этим ответили на мой второй вопрос. Я как раз и хотел узнать про примерный порядок величин. Узнал, спасибо)